# Nvidia Driver 440.59

Tags: nvidia, gpu-driver

I recently moved to linux 100% since now we have proton which is realy great. Today I see in my drivers that I can switch to 440.59. My current driver is working well. Should I update to this new one? It says that one of features it contains requires kernel 5.5 but I am on 5.3 atm. Gtx 1070 and ryzen 2700x are specs. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Readers who want a quick answer please skip to the last paragraph of this answer.

There's not much difference between Nvidia drivers in the *upgrade* direction. The later version of the Nvidia driver will usually have a little bit better performance, but you can use either version and either of the versions will work, however there can be a real difference between the two Nvidia drivers in the *downgrade* direction. Sometimes the older Nvidia driver will not work at all with your GPU because it's not compatible with it. If that little performance boost doesn't matter to you, then stay with the older driver version that is known to work and you won't have any problems.

That explains upgrading vs. downgrading Nvidia drivers, but there is the additional matter of getting the Nvidia driver version right the first time, so you don't need to either upgrade or downgrade it. Ubuntu has a built-in ubuntu-drivers program that can decide automatically which proprietary graphics drivers to install, and streamlines the installation of Nvidia drivers. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install   
sudo reboot
```

`sudo ubuntu-drivers install` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.

The `devices` command of `ubuntu-drivers` lists proprietary drivers that are compatible with your computer's GPU. If your computer has an Intel processor and it doesn't have a discrete graphics processor, the command `ubuntu-drivers devices` will not return results that show that a proprietary graphics card driver is available to be installed because the Intel graphics driver is built-in in Ubuntu.

If you visit the official NVIDIA website you will often see that the latest version of the proprietary graphics driver for your GPU is a little bit more up-to-date than the version of the same graphics driver that is available from the default Ubuntu repositories. Don't worry about this, because if the difference between version numbers of the two proprietary graphics drivers is small, then you will get similar performance by using either of the two drivers.

If you are currently using the nvidia-driver-435 proprietary graphics driver, I don't think there would be much benefit in upgrading it from version 435 to version 440, compared to the advantage of staying with nvidia-driver-435 from the default Ubuntu repositories. If you install a graphics driver from the default Ubuntu repositories, you will also get automatic updates for that driver which are sometimes linked to kernel updates.

Comment: it's unclear to me the relationship between what is shown in `ubuntu-drivers` and what ubuntu's software updates offer me.  for instance, the latter wants me to upgrade to 440, but claims it's the "open source" version.  Doing so breaks my ability to log in and I can't seem to downgrade because installing 430 always tries to pull in 440. but `ubuntu-drivers list` also shows a 435 and 440 driver, is this non-free?  are these already installed?

Comment: @Michael My *Software & Updates* -> *Additional Drivers* tab lists nvidia-driver-390, nvidia-driver-435 and nvidia-driver-440, and all three are listed as proprietary. The nvidia-driver-435 is marked as installed, and it was installed automatically by `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. nvidia-driver-440 is not marked as installed. In Ubuntu you must uninstall the existing proprietary graphics driver and reboot before you are able to install a different version proprietary graphics driver. nouveau is the open source driver for Nvidia graphics cards and is used in Ubuntu as a fallback driver.

Comment: nouveau can be installed alongside another Nvidia proprietary graphics driver.

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't obvious to me which ones if any where installed from the `list`. Is it possible to individually install or uninstall specific proprietary versions of the driver?

Comment: @Michael You can uninstall the existing version of the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver from the terminal. First you must remove any proprietary graphics driver PPAs and run `sudo apt update` to update the list of available software. Then run a uninstall command of the form `sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-XXX && sudo reboot`. Alternatively you can do the same thing graphically in Synaptic package manager (`sudo apt install synaptic`).

Comment: That's the thing that confuses me... i see "nvidia-driver-440" in both `ubuntu-drivers` which is supposed to be propriety, but also ubuntu software updates which is *not*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107660/discussion-between-karel-and-michael).